# add an image instead of an object on canvas to exhibit zoom/scale property

Tags: javascript, canvas

I want to add an image on the canvas and then zoom/Scale it

I am trying to add this image file but unable to do so though I can add square and then zoom the canvas.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/houseIcon.png

how can I add the image.

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ndYdk/11/

```
function draw(scale, translatePos){
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

// clear canvas
context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

context.save();
context.translate(translatePos.x, translatePos.y);
context.scale(scale, scale);
context.beginPath(); // begin custom shape
  context.rect(20, 20, 50, 50);
  context.fillStyle = 'red';
  context.fill();
  context.lineWidth = 2;
  context.strokeStyle = 'black';
  context.stroke();
context.closePath(); // complete custom shape
var grd = context.createLinearGradient(-59, -100, 81, 100);

context.fillStyle = grd;
context.fill();

context.stroke();
context.restore();
 }
```

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: what difficulties did you run into ? You seem very close from the result.

Comment: Hi @GameAlchemist I have figured that problem.. This is working but I want the image to be stick to canvas and doesn't move around the canvas but I want a scroll-er when I zoom in.  How can I add that feature.
http://jsfiddle.net/ndYdk/20/

Comment: @GameAlchemist Can you suggest something I can try for this problem.

Comment: jsfiddle seems not to be working now, which complicate things. Update your question please (maybe usinng jsbin ?).

Comment: @GameAlchemist try clicking the zoom in button and the image will appear.

Comment: i'm sorry i don't understand well enough what you seek. Edit your question with the new fiddle and wanted feature / issue description please.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24169981/add-a-scrollbar-when-image-is-zoomed-in I have added the question here.

Comment: ok, so you might delete this one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55534/discussion-between-user3594118-and-gamealchemist).