# Add A scrollbar when image is zoomed in

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to add a scroll bar when the image zoom in. 
The problem I am facing now is my image is not intact with the canvas I can move the image around even if its not zoomed in or scaled.

I want the image to be intact to the canvas and when its zoom in, the scroll bar should appear.
I have added the overflow to auto  in the CSS.

```
#container
{
    position: relative;
      overflow:auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ndYdk/21/

Sometimes the image doesnt appear at first so just click zoom in/out and it will appear.

Any Help is really appreciated

Comment: What do you mean by "intact to" the canvas?

Comment: Is your problem that you don't have a scrollbar or that your "image is not intact with the canvas"(don't know what that means).

Comment: @zatch_rulz I dont have a scroll bar . it doesnt appear when I zoom in the image. The image is not intact as I am able to move around the image in the canvas. I want a image which is on the canvas and doesnt move by mouse down. Thats y i want a scroller so as when the image zis zoomed in, i can see the hidden parts by using the scroller instead of mouse down and mouse move.

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with the code in the jsfiddle? It explicit has "event listeners to handle screen drag." If you want the image to not move around, disable that when you are zoomed in.

However, the thing with the scrollbar is a bit trickier. The correct solution would be having the `overflow: scroll` and a set height/width in your `<div id="container">` itself, however this would add a scrollbar if the canvas size itself got bigger, not if the contents in the canvas changed size, as they do know.

You could try to add scrollbars manually when you detect your image is larger than your canvas. one way to do that is here: [Canvas Scrollbar not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15385290/canvas-scrollbar-not-working)

However, an easier way may be to just put the size constraints and overflow on your parent div as I said above and then change the actual size of the canvas.

Answer (score -2):

It looks like the canvas tag does not support the overflow CSS rule since this does not force the browser's scroll to appear:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" style="overflow:scroll;" "></canvas>
```

There are interesting topics in Google that could help you with your task:
https://www.google.com/search?q=show+scroll+inside+canvas+tag